# iOS Simulator Thinks Documents Directory is /var/root/Documents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to read all the files in the simulator in the Documents directory, but I get a Cocoa error 260. When I log `[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]`, it says /var/root/Documents. Anyone know why this would happen? It only happens when I run from the command line. When running in the simulator itself the code correctly outputs the right documents folder for the simulator.

*UPDATE* I am seeing a path of "file://localhost/Users/MyUserName/Documents" now. So weird...

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by running from the command line?

Comment: We are running our unit tests via command line, but I already found the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to chmod -R 777 "/Users/MyUserName/Documents" and then change my method to this:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:basePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: Create documents folder failed %@", basePath);
    }

    return basePath;
}
```